# Is YouTube legally required to not allow "Made For Kids" videos to be added to playlists?

Tags: internet, privacy, data-protection, youtube, coppa

In the last few years YouTube introduced a *Made For Kids* classification for videos, which requires uploaders to state whether a given video is made for children, in which case [certain features](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9527654#what_happens&zippy=%2Cif-you-set-a-video-or-live-stream-as-made-for-kids) are disabled for those videos. YouTube cites the (American) COPPA legislation and data privacy as the reason for this change.

One of the features that a *Made for Kids* category disables is the ability to add those videos to a playlist. This has always confused me, as the data collection link to it isn't immediately apparent, and I imagine it's quite a significant pain for parents who want to create a playlist of lullabies for their kids, for example.

To compound this, the language of the *Made for Kids* option when uploading videos to YouTube is ambiguous enough to frequently be confused for a "family-friendly" option, resulting in uploaders often mistakenly marking their videos with the classification and limiting their functionality for general viewers as a result. This is especially the case in non-English markets, as evidenced by the many non-English videos I've seen marked as *Made for Kids* which were almost definitely intended to be general audience.

Therefore, given that the disabling of playlists on videos that are *Made for Kids* seems to hurt everyone and benefit no-one, what exactly is YouTube's logic for the necessity of doing so? Does COPPA actually require it, or is it a case of YouTube being overly cautious?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://politics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Politics? It's literally about the law and why a large corporation made a particular decision to comply with it. If politics is involved at all it's a byproduct, not the primary background of the question.

Comment: "...why a large corporation made a particular decision..." is not a question of law; it's a question of business practice decisions and/or politics.

Comment: I am not sure if the question is on-topic here or not (it would require to know if the decission not to allow to include videos in playlist is effectively linked to COPPA) but certainly it does not belong on [politics.se].

Comment: @SJuan76: +1, YouTube is not a government, its policies are not political.

Comment: I'd think the specific question "Does COPPA actually require it" [given YouTube's other policies around these videos] is a question of law?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Granted, the item "*Youtube's logic for doing so*" is something that only Youtube can answer with precision, but the substance of the OP's question is on topic. Someone with knowledge, or enough interest, on the matter can identify whether Youtube's requirement is or seems premised on the COPPA or related legislation. The OP ultimately is interested in the *legal* aspect of a business decision rather than the *actual* motivation therefor.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about a private companies policies.